# Enforce echarts' force-directed graph layout to remain unchanged regardless of node values

Tags: echarts

I need to colour-code different values on my graph. The problem is that as soon as I change node values, the layout of graph will change which is not convenient.

I tried using a circular layout initialisation as well as setting actual initial positions of the nodes, but both solutions failed.

```
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/echarts/5.2.2/echarts.min.js'></script>
<div id='main' style='width: 100vh;;height:100vh;'></div>
<script type='text/javascript'>
document.addEventListener('contextmenu', event => event.preventDefault());
var myChart = echarts.init(document.getElementById('main'));
myChart.showLoading();
graph = {
    'nodes': [{
        'name': 'node1',
        'value': 183
    }, {
        'name': 'node2',
        'value': 500
    }, {
        'name': 'node3',
        'value': 139
    }, {
        'name': 'node4',
        'value': 10
    }],
    'links': [{
        'source': 'node1',
        'target': 'node2'
    }, {
        'source': 'node2',
        'target': 'node3'
    }, {
        'source': 'node3',
        'target': 'node1'
    }, {
        'source': 'node1',
        'target': 'node4'
    }]
};
var max_value = Math.max.apply(Math, graph.nodes.map(function(o) {
    return o.value;
}));
var min_value = Math.min.apply(Math, graph.nodes.map(function(o) {
    return o.value;
}));
myChart.hideLoading();
myChart.setOption(option = {
    visualMap: {
        min: min_value,
        max: max_value,
        precision: 2,
        calculable: true,
        realtime: true,
        orient: 'horizontal',
        left: 'center',
        top: 'top',
        color: ['#800026', '#ffffcc']
    },
    animationDurationUpdate: 1500,
    animationEasingUpdate: 'quinticInOut',
    series: [{
        type: 'graph',
        layout: 'force',
        force: {
            initLayout: 'circular'
        },
        symbolSize: 10,
        roam: true,
        zoom: 3,
        label: {
            show: false
        },
        emphasis: {
            focus: 'adjacency',
            label: {
                show: false
            }
        },
        edgeSymbol: ['circle'],
        edgeSymbolSize: [4, 10],
        edgeLabel: {
            fontSize: 20
        },
        data: graph['nodes'],
        links: graph['links'],
        lineStyle: {
            opacity: 0.9,
            width: 2,
            curveness: 0
        }
    }]
});
</script>
```

Here is the [corresponding fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ahassaine/903s18tf/1/).

Comment: hello, you can add this   

   " force: {
                initLayout: 'circular',
                layoutAnimation: false //<=
            } "
    
but it still move randomly sometimes.. if you find better or other solution, please let me know

Comment: is there maybe a way to get X Y coordinate from nodes when they have been placed by force constraint in the layout? then draw one time the graph with force, save the coordinate, draw the other times without force option and use coordinate X Y stored and the parameter coordinateSystem: 'cartesian2d' ?